# UITextField horizontal text alignment - text not centered

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a very strange bug trying to **horizontally center** text in `UITextField` object in iOS 7+ app.

I have set up a fresh project to isolate the bug and to make sure I'm not doing something wrong.

In `viewDidAppear:` method I alloc/init a new `UITextField` instance like this:

```
UITextField *tf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60.0f, 100.0f, 200.0f, 200.0f)];
tf.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
tf.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

[self.view addSubview:tf];
```

That's all. When I run this sample app on **iPhone Retina (4-inch 64-bit) simulator** I get following result:

[image]

**After typing in some letters I get this:**

[image]

Do anyone know what's is happening? The text should be centered while typing.
I didn't come across this bug till now. It is iOS related or am I doing something wrong?

P.s.: It is happening on iDevices also.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:

Adding:

```
tf.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
tf.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
```

doesn't help either.

**EDIT 2**:

Like *Inder Kumar Rathore* suggested I tried to set a **height** to 20.0f like so:

```
UITextField *tf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60.0f, 100.0f, 200.0f, 20.0f)];
```

and it surprisingly works. But it doens't solve the issue. I discovered that increasing **height** from 20.0f up makes issue only worse. I think it has something to do with **line-height**/**text field height** ratio. I don't know..

Comment: Strange behavior, though decreasing the height to 20 make it work absolutely fine.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore Thanks for your comment. I tried that and I works but that doesn't solve the issue. I also discovered that increasing height from 20 up makes issue only worse. Like it would be some kind of size ratio related issue. I don't have a clue what is going on :/

Comment: UITextField is intended to use for a single line of text. Why you want to increase the height of textfield. you may want to use UITextview

Comment: @Anil Yes, but that doesn't solve nor explain the issue. It shouldn't matter if you ask me.

Comment: Looks like the problem starts becoming easily apparent around 70 height. It is still a little strange when the text approaches the width of the container at lesser heights, but around 70 is when the non-centering starts happening noticeably sooner.

Comment: @Stonz2 I agree. I think it is all about line-height (font size) vs text field height ratio. Hmmm..

Comment: The total width of the field appears to matter as well, as it seems to get confused as the field contents approach the container width (with this being more pronounced and happening earlier in a taller container)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `UITextField` expects the vertical size of the font to be equivalent to the height of the text field. If you imagine a font at a point size that will fill the vertical height of your text field at 200 points, you will only be able to type a few characters before it fills the horizontal width and switches from the centered behavior to the right-aligned behavior. This seems to be the behavior in your "bug" above, where you can only type a few characters before it switches behaviors.

I think the best thing to do is to make your text field just high enough to fit your font, and vertically center it in a containing `UIView`.

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't explain nor solve my issue. I already knew that this would "fix" my issue but I wanted an explanation of it. Anyway, I'm going to accept your answer because it is a solution.